# C++ ambiguous overload and constructor with defaults

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, default-value, overloading

I have a program with a code that works simply perfectly but compiler still outputs this annoying warning:

```
warning: ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second:
```

The simplyfied version of my program is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

class point
{
public:
    point( int x = 0, int y = 0 )

    :   _x( x ), _y( y )
    {}

    point( const point &p )
    :   _x( p._x ), _y( p._y )
    {}

    int &   x( )    {   return _x;  }
    int &   y( )    {   return _y;  }

private:
    int _x, _y;
};

class matrix
{
public:
    int operator()( int x, int y )  const
    {   return _array[ index( x, y ) ]; }

    int operator()( point< int > p )        const
    {   return operator()( p.x( ), p.y( ) );    }

    int operator()( int x, int y, int value )
    {
        _array[ index( x, y ) ] = value;
        return _array[ index( x, y ) ];
    }

    int operator()( point< int > p, int value )
    {   return operator()( p.x( ), p.y( ), value ); }

private:
    int _array[ 4 * 5 ];

    int index( int x, int y )   const
    {   return y * Width + x;   }
};

int main( )
{
    std::cout << "Filling matrix." << std::endl;
    matrix< int, 4, 5 > m;

    for ( int y = 0; y < 5; ++y )
        for ( int x = 0; x < 4; ++x )
        {
            m( x, y, ( y * 4 + x ) );
        }

    std::cout << "Reading matrix." << std::endl;

    for ( int y = 0; y < 5; ++y )
    {
        std::cout << std::endl << "|";

        for ( int x = 0; x < 4; ++x )
        {
            std::cout << std::setw( 3 ) << std::setfill( ' ' ) << m( x, y ) << " |";
        }
    }

    std::cout << std::endl << "Done." << std::endl;
}
```

I can't see what's wrong with my `operator()` overloads.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well,

it took me some time to figure out the actual reason of this warning. Since my program was running fine, I simply neglected the warning until today and I thought it would be useful to share it so other people around the world can save some time.

After a lot of tinkering around the `operator()` constructions I decided to take a look upside and wonder why would my compiler be confusing a single value with a `point` and taking the second argument as `value`.

And I found out that I have lazily added default values for my `point` constructor so I'd be able to use it as a default constructor as well.
When I added this defaults I wasn't paying attention that anyone could use this constructor by omitting only the second argument and this led to my error.

## ** The dangers of being inattentive! **

Just for funny, I changed my constructor as below:

```
#ifdef  AMBIGUOUS
    point( int x = 0, int y = 0 )
#else
    point( )
    : point( 0, 0 ) {}

    point( int x, int y )
#endif
```

And then I could try my solution before cleaning it up with:

```
> g++ ambig_param.cpp -o ambig_param -Wall -std=c++14
```

Ok. Compiles without an issue while the later:

```
> g++ ambig_param.cpp -o ambig_param -Wall -std=c++14 -DAMBIGUOUS
ambig_param.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
ambig_param.cpp:68:66: warning: ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second:
    std::cout << std::setw( 3 ) << std::setfill( ' ' ) << m( x, y ) << " |";
                                                                  ^
ambig_param.cpp:27:4: note: candidate 1: T matrix<T>::operator()(T, T) const [with T = int]
  T operator()( T x, T y ) const
    ^~~~~~~~
ambig_param.cpp:39:4: note: candidate 2: T matrix<T>::operator()(point<int>, T) [with T = int]
  T operator()( point< int > p, T value )
    ^~~~~~~~
```

I hope it may help someone one day.